# React native expo - programatically get default font family in android

Tags: react-native

How to get default font-family used in react-native android? I want to use custom font only if user changes the default OS font else we want to go with standard android font.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you don't define any font family in your project, it falls back to the default font of the OS.

Comment: This is not what I want. I want to know default font that will be applied programatically.

Comment: Oh okay. I dont think there is a way to do it in RN at the moment, but you can create a bridge, and get the system fonts from iOS and Android with a request. Maybe create a package that does it.

Comment: that's a good suggestion. Can we even get default font in android native? Any idea?